# Regarding reversible phase transition of a real gas

Tags: thermodynamics

According to change in entropy for a reversible phase transition, say from liquid to gas at constant pressure $p$ and temperature $T$

: $\Delta S =\frac{\int dq_p}{T} $  which comes out to be $\Delta S =\frac{\Delta H_{vap}}{T_b}$. This means that this process is spontaneous since Entropy change is positive. But the Gibb's Energy change for this process is $0$. Why is that?

Change in entropy for this process suggests that this is a spontaneous process but Gibb's Energy change suggests it is not. Why does irregularity occur?

Comment: A positive change in entropy does not necessarily mean that a process is spontaneous.  Where did you get that idea?  That is only true for an isolated system.

Comment: [See the answer I have written here, I have derived spontaneity condition of Gibb's from scratch](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/149493/gibbs-free-energy-intuition/579239#579239)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\Delta S_\mathrm{sys} =\frac{\Delta H_\mathrm{vap}}{T_b}$$

is the entropy change of the system.

$$\frac {\Delta G}{T_\mathrm{b}} = \Delta S_\mathrm{tot} = \Delta S_\mathrm{ext} + \Delta S_\mathrm{sys} = \Delta S_\mathrm{ext} + \frac{\Delta H_\mathrm{vap}}{T_b} = 0$$

is proportional to the total entropy change.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 unreasonable points your question raised.
Firstly, you made a mistake when you transformed $\triangle S = \frac{\int dq_p}{T}$, because $dq$ should equals $-dH_{sys}$. The above answer replicated that mistake too. Because $\triangle S_{sys}$ is state function, it can not be transformed like that, actually $\triangle S_{ext} = \frac{\int -dH_{sys}}{T}$, so $\triangle S_{tot} = \triangle S_{sys} - \frac{\triangle H_{sys}}{T}$. (those equations can be found in any physical chemistry books).

Secondly, you can not distinguish between standard-state Gibbs energy and Gibbs energy. We have that: $\triangle G = \triangle G^o + RTlnQ$ with Q is the proportion of component. In order to make one reaction spontaneous, Gibbs energy $(\triangle G)$ should equal 0, even though whatever $\triangle G^o$ is.

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to say. According to https://web.mit.edu/16.unified/www/FALL/thermodynamics/notes/node41.html the change in entropy of the **system** for a reversible process is in fact $\int \frac{dq}{T}$. It was just that in this case the pressure and temperature were constant because of the phase transition. So the heat flow is equal to the change in enthalpy $\Delta H_{sys}$. And for $\Delta G$ I applied the equation $\Delta G= \Delta H - T\Delta S$.

Comment: Q is defined as an amount of heat transferred to out of the system. However, change of enthalpy is defined as change of heat of the system. So, $\triangle H_{system}$ must have different sign regarding to $Q$ or $\triangle H_{system} = - Q$.

Comment: Additionally, we assume that: $\triangle S_{tot} = \triangle S_{sys} + \triangle S_{ext} = \triangle S_{sys}+ \frac{-\triangle H_{sys}}{T}$<br/>So: $\triangle H_{sys}-T\times \triangle S_{sys} = -T\times \triangle S_{tot} =-\triangle G^o_{sys}$ (let's remember $\triangle G^o$, not $\triangle G$)

Comment: NO!! change of enthalpy **IS NOT** defined as change of heat of the system at all. This statement is only true for isobaric process. $\Delta H=q_p$, $\Delta H$ will not be equal to actual heat transfer in the system. Q is not defined as the amount of heat transferred **out of the system**. It is simply the transfer of heat in or out of the system. It doesn't matter if it is coming in or going out.

Comment: $Q_p$ and $Q$ are different, my friend. These make physchem so hard.

Comment: I'm not saying they're the same. I'm saying $\Delta H\neq Q$ except for isobaric processes.

Comment: Yeah, but different sign. Sign of any quantity depends on how we define it.

Comment: No, not just different sign but they are not even numerically equal.